# SQL Server date conversion - yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:s

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, casting

do you know how i can convert yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in SQL server 2008?

I tried `SELECT convert(varchar, StateChangeTime, 120) from History` but it cant tell the diff between the 9th as a month and a day for example so does nothing.
stateChangeTime is a dateTime2

example date i want to convert `2013-03-09 19:29:25` should be `2013-09-03 19:29:25`

Help!

Comment: I'm missing something here. If you call the `CONVERT()` function asking for string-type output, like varchar, then it expects a date-type input, like datetime. But you're talking like `StateChangeTime` is also a varchar. Either you're doing something really bad by storing date values as strings (don't do that!), or you're confused about how datetime values are really stored. Datetime values are stored in an unreadable binary format, and only shown in a way you can read by the query tool for display.

Comment: There is no yyyy-dd-mm format among any of the formats that SQL Server recognises, so you would need to chop the string up in the components and rearrange them.

Comment: stateChangeTime is a dateTime2 type, updated question

Comment: @Guffa- ok, i populated the table from a excel file which explains the weird format, can you show me how to chop it up and re-arrange??

Answer (score 1):

1. This is my understanding: Your source is stored in `VARCHAR` format (not as `datetime`).
2. You want to convert that custom-format string source into a parse-able format.

Try these ms-SQL statements:

```
/*****
Your Source is in a custom-format string */
DECLARE @vsInpYYYYDDMM varchar(64)
SET @vsInpYYYYDDMM = '2013-03-09 19:29:25'

/*****
Convert that source YYYY-DD-MM format to YYYY-MM-DD format */
DECLARE @vsActualYYYYMMDD varchar(64)
SET @vsActualYYYYMMDD = substring( @vsInpYYYYDDMM, 1,4) + '-' + substring( @vsInpYYYYDDMM, 9, 2) + '-' + substring(@vsInpYYYYDDMM, 6, 2) + ' ' + substring(@vsInpYYYYDDMM,12,99)

PRINT @vsActualYYYYMMDD + ' is a String'

/*****
Convert that into an actual DATETIME variable */
DECLARE @dtDateVar as datetime
SET @dtDateVar = CONVERT( datetime, @vsActualYYYYMMDD, 120)
PRINT CONVERT(varchar, @dtDateVar, 120) + ' is a DateTime'
```

Answer (score -1):

How are you storing your dates in SQL Server ? is it a `datetime` column type. If it is, then the formatting is being applied in the way it's being displayed to you (due to locale settings).

`121` formatter option will return it as a string in the format you want.

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 121)
--returns 2013-09-24 15:51:14.363
```

If on the otherhand it's being stored as a string, then you're going to need to do a little bit of string manipulation on it.

Comment: If the date is stored as a string, you can try casting or converting the string to a `datetime` and then use the `convert` function as described in this answer.

Comment: yes, but if it's a string, and it's been stored yyyy-dd-mm due to something on the client, and the server locale is expecting yyyy-mm-dd, then the server is going to parse that string arse-ways and transpose the mm & dd for August 9th & September 8th.

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted, it is what I was hoping to find